# How to fetch data from an api and store it in a database with nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, database

I want to clone a public api into a mongodb database with nodejs so I can run my own queries and extend the data like I want. My problem is that I want to fetch the newest updates as well. The good thing is that I know when the data will change at the api app approximately.

I thought about something like cronjobs or a setInterval.
In the internet I could find many solutions how to transform a database into a rest api but no vice versa.

Please give me suggestions how to solve this problem.

Comment: Cron Jobs is nothing but a way to automate a script's execution. In your case I would suggest that you should make a script that will fetch the new data from the api and it will be saved in your database - either by replacing the previous data or new addition. The logic is dependent on what you want. Now the choice is yours if you want to automate the operation of this updation or you can manually execute the script with whatever inputs it requires.

Comment: How to automate this best?

Comment: I have already answered that. Everything depends on your requirement and your demands. What suits you best is the best way to do it.